# Filtering DataFrames in Pandas for multiple columns where a column name contains a pattern

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, filter, multiple-columns

While filtering multiple columns I have seen examples where we could filter Rows using something like this `df[df['A'].str.contains("string") | df['B'].str.contains("string")]` .

I have multiple files where I want to fetch each file and get only those rows with `'gmail.com'` from the column names having `'email'` string in them.

So an example header can be like: 'firstname' 'lastname' 'companyname' 'address' 'emailid1' 'emailid2' 'emailid3' ...

The columns `emailid1..2..3` have emailids containing `gmail.com`. I would want to fetch rows where gmail can occur in any one of them.

```
for file in files:
    pdf = pd.read_csv('Reduced/'+file,delimiter = '\t')
    emailids = [col for col in pdf.columns if 'email' in col]
    #  pdf['gmail' in pdf[emailids]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given example input of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email': ['test@example.com', 'someone@gmail.com'], 'somethingelse': [1, 2], 'another_email': ['whatever@example.com', 'something@example.com']})
```

eg:

```
           another_email              email  somethingelse
0   whatever@example.com   test@example.com              1
1  something@example.com  someone@gmail.com              2
```

You can filter out the columns that contain email, look for `gmail.com` or whatever text you wish, then subset, eg:

```
df[df.filter(like='email').applymap(lambda L: 'gmail.com' in L).any(axis=1)]
```

Which gives you:

```
           another_email              email  somethingelse
1  something@example.com  someone@gmail.com              2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'email1':['gmail.com','t','f'],
                   'email2':['u','gmail.com','t'],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})
print (pdf)
   A  D  E  F     email1     email2
0  1  1  5  7  gmail.com          u
1  2  3  3  4          t  gmail.com
2  3  5  6  3          f          t

#filter column names                   
emailids = [col for col in pdf.columns if 'email' in col]
print (emailids)
['email1', 'email2']

#apply string function for each filtered column
df = pd.concat([pdf[col].str.contains('gmail.com') for col in pdf[emailids]], axis=1)

print (df)
  email1 email2
0   True  False
1  False   True
2  False  False

#filter at least one True by any
print (pdf[df.any(1)])
   A  D  E  F     email1     email2
0  1  1  5  7  gmail.com          u
1  2  3  3  4          t  gmail.com
```